# How can I rewrite an arbitrarily nested field in a JSON structure using haskell lenses?

Tags: json, haskell, haskell-lens, aeson

I would like to make the following test pass:

```
it "can rewrite a field from an object" $ do
  let _42 = 42 :: Int
      nested =  object [ "foo" .= _42, "baz" .= object [ "bar" .= _42 ] ]
                                           ]
  rewrite "bar" nested  `shouldBe` object [ "foo" .= _42
                                          , "baz" .= object [ "bar" .= ("XXXXXXXX" :: Text) ]
                                          ]
```

It seems that what I want is something from `Control.Lens.Plated` like [rewrite](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.2/docs/Control-Lens-Plated.html#v:rewrite) like or [transform](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.2/docs/Control-Lens-Plated.html#v:transform) but I cannot manage to make it work, probably due to missing deep understanding of lenses.

I managed to change a single layer using the following code but would like to leverage that to nested fields.

```
 rewrite' field value = value & key field %~ const "XXXXXXXX"
```

Comment: Does `\field -> transform (rewrite' field)` do what you want? (Just a guess - I'm no lens expert either)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to use [`transformOn`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.2/docs/Control-Lens-Plated.html#v:transformOn) along with [`deep`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.2/docs/Control-Lens-Plated.html#v:deep) to get precise control over the where the transformation is applied.

```
ghci> let nested = object [ "foo" .= 42, "baz" .= object [ "bar" .= 42 ] ]
ghci> transformOn (deep $ key "bar") (const "XXXXXXXX") nested
Object (fromList [("foo",Number 42.0),("baz",Object (fromList [("bar",String "XXXXXXXX")]))])
```

`deep` searches a `Plated` structure for locations where the provided `Traversal` matches, and `transformOn` applies a change to each of its targets.

**EDIT:**

I just realized `transformOn` is massive overkill for this.  You can get away with just `deep` and simpler lens combinators:

```
ghci> deep (key "bar") %~ const "XXXXXXXX" $ nested
Object (fromList [("foo",Number 42.0),("baz",Object (fromList [("bar",String "XXXXXXXX")]))])
```

or even

```
ghci> deep (key "bar") .~ "XXXXXXXX" $ nested
Object (fromList [("foo",Number 42.0),("baz",Object (fromList [("bar",String "XXXXXXXX")]))])
```

The `transform*` family of functions applies its modifications recursively, which is overkill for the modification you want to make.